# Windows Universal Apps - Clearing In-App-Purchases

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a tested app that will hopefully go live in the short term.

However, it has 3 in app purchases.

If the situation arises where I need to do a further test of purchasing the in-app-purchases, is there any way I can cancel my own personal in-app-purchases up to that point so I will be testing from scratch?

Note: I am using the new `Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext` method, and not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no such API that can cancel your in-app-purchase currently. But you can still do your further test.

> If the situation arises where I need to do a further test of
>   purchasing the in-app-purchases, is there any way I can cancel my own
>   personal in-app-purchases up to that point so I will be testing from
>   scratch?

According to your description, it seems your IAP type is durable. If so, you can specify the duration for the product as 1 day so that you can repurchase it after it expires.

If your IAP is developer-managed consumable type, you need to report the previous IAP as fulfilled after the user consumes all the items. Then they purchase it again.

If your IAP is Store-managed consumable type, you need to report any items consumed by user as fulfilled to the Store and the Store updates user's balance. After users consume all the items, the user can purchase that IAP again.

For more details, you may refer to **[In-app purchases and trials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#basic-concepts)**.

Comment: My IAP is durable. In testing (prior to going live) I have it set to 1 day, as suggested in the documentation. (Note: You should do a 10 minute duration, so programmers can test stuff a bit more quickly before launch.) The question I have relates to when it goes live. Say I have all iap purchased on my machine, but a users says they are having a bit of trouble in a specific case I need to test. If I change the iap from permanent to 1 day so I lose it so I can test the problem case, that means every user that has purchased this **permanent** iap up to this point will also lose it like myself.

Comment: Since there's no API to cancel your IAP purchase, the workaround is to create a separate hidden IAP to test your specific case. Regarding 10-minute-duration, you could create a feature request at [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) site so that MSFT might will add it to their to-do-list. The dev team is also trying to simplify the IAP testing process. Thanks for your understanding.